# How are colons used with ivars?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm doing some code refactoring and I've come across some ivars syntax that I haven't seen before. The code looks like

```
@interface Object : NSObject {
@private BOOL aBool:1;
}
@end
```

My question is, what does the `:1` do?

Comment: Never seen that. Interested to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This syntax has the same meaning for an ivar as it does inside a struct; you're declaring a bitfield of the specified size.

This likely doesn't have any effect on the actual size of the class in this case -- I don't think you can allocate less than a byte -- but the compiler will warn you if you try to put a value into the variable that's too large for the bitfield size you indicated:

```
@interface BittyBoop : NSObject
{
    unsigned char bit:1;
    unsigned char bits:4;
}

@end

@implementation BittyBoop

- (void)doThatThingIDo
{
    bit = 2;    // Implicit truncation from 'int' to bitfield changes value from 2 to 0
    bits = 2;   // no warning
}

@end
```

Comment: So for the case of BOOL, which has NO or YES (0 or 1), all this the :1 is doing nothing?

Comment: Not quite nothing, because normally you can address all 8 bits of a `BOOL` (it's a typedef'd `unsigned char`). This may be an attempt to avoid some of [`BOOL`'s sharp corners](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bools-sharp-corners/).